# Windows Server 1804: how to copy files from remote machine?

Tags: windows

Windows Server 1804, just like 1709, has no UI - only terminal. I need to copy files from another Windows machine to Windows Server 1804 machine.

How to do that? (I was trying to use WinSCP, but it can't connect to Windows Server machine).

Comment: Why down-vote? I think that is a legitimate question...

Comment: It is - if you are totally cluless and have no business being on windows server core. If you are a profressional admin (which this site here caters to) then your question is seriously an admittance of utter incompetence. As such, downvote.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I mapped remote folder using this command:

```
Net use y: \\remoteaddress\folder
```

After that, I was able to perform a regular copy action as between two local folders.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP is a client that is used to connect to FTP/SFTP and similar protocols. As long as there is none of this enabled on the server, WinSCP won't help you here.

You would have to create a SMB share on the server with the command line tool `net share` which you can connect to from any other windows computer.

[How to create Windows Shares with `net share`](https://www.windows-commandline.com/list-create-delete-network-shares/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the net use command from the other answer with the admin share C$ on the remote server of another drive$ with robocopy.